# can't check if integer is withing a range java

Tags: java, if-statement, range

ok i've spent a while trying to find a solution for this i even checked the post:

but i still can't figure out how to do what i want my problem is the following: when i go to check if the value is in the given range it only checks the first value for example 32 and ignore the rest here is the code. Please help don't just take me to a different post i'm new with java i'll really appreciate your help

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox;

public class Disneyland {

    protected Shell shell;
    private Text textHeight;
    private String height; 

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Disneyland window = new Disneyland();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Disneyland.class, "/Images/1000px-Disneyland_Park_Logo.svg.png"));
        shell.setSize(600, 400);
        shell.setText("Disneyland Park Height Requirements");

        Label lblNewLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Disneyland.class, "/Images/disney_magin_disneyland_6899.png"));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(233, 10, 128, 134);

        Label lblNewLabel_1 = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel_1.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(0, 51, 255));
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("MathJax_Fraktur", 18, SWT.NORMAL));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(125, 166, 349, 27);
        lblNewLabel_1.setText("Please input your height in inches\n");

        textHeight = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        textHeight.setBounds(233, 213, 128, 27);

        Button btnSubmit = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnSubmit.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_TRANSPARENT));
        btnSubmit.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Disneyland.class, "/Images/disney.gif"));
        btnSubmit.setBounds(274, 261, 56, 45);
        btnSubmit.addListener(SWT.Selection, new submitButtonListener());

    }
    public class submitButtonListener implements Listener {


        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            height = textHeight.getText();

        if(Integer.parseInt(height)<32 ){






            MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK  );
            messagebox.setText("Height limitations");
            messagebox.setMessage("For your own safety you are only allowed to use the rides with Any Height signs under adult supervision. We hope you grow up very quick :)");
            messagebox.open();
            }else{
        if(Integer.parseInt(height)==32 & Integer.parseInt(height)<35   ){






            MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK  );
            messagebox.setText("Height limitations");
            messagebox.setMessage("You are allowed to go on the Autopia accompanied by another rider 54 inches or taller");
            messagebox.open();
            }
        if(Integer.parseInt(height)== 35 & Integer.parseInt(height) < 40 ){






            MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK  );
            messagebox.setText("Height limitations");
            messagebox.setMessage("You are allowed to go on the Autopia and the Gadget's Go Coaster accompanied by another rider 54 inches or taller");
            messagebox.open();
            }
    if(Integer.parseInt(height)== 40 & Integer.parseInt(height)<42 ){






            MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK  );
            messagebox.setText("Height limitations");
            messagebox.setMessage("You are allowed to go on the Autopia, Gadget's Go Coaster, the Big Thunder Mountain Railroad, Space Mountain, Splash Mountain and Star Tours accompanied by another rider 54 inches or taller");
            messagebox.open();
            }
    if(Integer.parseInt(height)== 42 & Integer.parseInt(height)<46 ){






        MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK  );
        messagebox.setText("Height limitations");
        messagebox.setMessage("You are allowed to go on the Autopia, Gadget's Go Coaster, the Big Thunder Mountain Railroad, Space Mountain, Splash Mountain, Star Tours and Matterhorn Bobsleds accompanied by another rider 54 inches or taller");
        messagebox.open();
        }
    if(Integer.parseInt(height)== 46 & Integer.parseInt(height) < 54 ){






        MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK  );
        messagebox.setText("Height limitations");
        messagebox.setMessage("You are allowed to go on the Autopia, Gadget's Go Coaster, the Big Thunder Mountain Railroad, Space Mountain, Splash Mountain, Star Tours, Matterhorn Bobsleds and Indiana Jones Adventure accompanied by another rider 54 inches or taller");
        messagebox.open();
        }

    if(Integer.parseInt(height)>= 54  ){






        MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK  );
        messagebox.setText("Height limitations");
        messagebox.setMessage("You are allowed to go on the Autopia without adult supervision" );
        messagebox.open();
        }
            }
    }

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(height)==32 && Integer.parseInt(height)<35` will only be true for 32. Did you mean `Integer.parseInt(height)>=32`?

Comment: yeah but when i do >=32 it will open all the windows that makes the statement >32 true

Comment: Why `if(Integer.parseInt(height)== 40 && Integer.parseInt(height)<42 )`?

Comment: @Benji2 Only those less than 35. Do you know what `&&` means?

Comment: i want the statement to be true if the values is between the range 40-42

Comment: sorry guys this is embarrassing but i'm not really used to java coming from php, if  there is a way to put the condition in the rage would you please help me

Comment: I tried. What's wrong with my suggestion?

Comment: It would be much easier to: parse `height` once, move the operations to methods, and use `if (height < 32) { ... } else if (height < 35) { ... } else if (height < 40) { ... } ` etc.

Comment: @shmosel i tried it and i'll still give me no input

Comment: You updated all the `if`s?

Comment: @shmosel I did!

Comment: Perhaps you can update the code to the latest, so that others can tell what changes have been made.

Comment: @PaulT. Updated!

Comment: You haven't changed anything, other than unnecessarily replacing `&&` with `&`.

Comment: `if(Integer.parseInt(height)==32 & Integer.parseInt(height)<35   ){` 1. Parsing the same thing multiple times. 2. bit wise AND instead of logical. 3. Stupid logic x==y && x<z? Only x==y matters in this case.

Comment: @Benji2: Know that range checking in Java is very similar to that in PHP (similar operators), so this should not be too big a deal.

Answer (score 0):

The following may help clarify the issues with the OP's `if` approach. In addition, it suggests moving some of the common code to a single point.

```
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
  // the title is always the same
  final String title = "Height limitations";

  // set the msg depending upon the discovered height
  String msg;

  // get value from box
  final height = textHeight.getText();

  // parse it once
  final int parsedHeight = Integer.parseInt(height);

  // set message depending upon height
  if (parsedHeight < 32) {
    msg = "For your own safety you are only allowed to use the rides with Any Height signs under adult supervision. We hope you grow up very quick :)";
  } else if (parseHeight < 35) {
    msg = "You are allowed to go on the Autopia accompanied by another rider 54 inches or taller";
  }
  ...


 //
 // no need to repeat all of the code in each block
 //      
 MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK  );
 messagebox.setText(title);
 messagebox.setMessage(msg);
 messagebox.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. change `==` to `>=` - this will check less than or equal.**

As a example,

`if(Integer.parseInt(height)>= 32 & Integer.parseInt(height) < 35 ){`

this condition will check for between 32(included) and 35(not included).

**2. Also change,**

`private String height;` to `private int height;`

Why? You are passing the same `height` `String` variable to `int` in so many places. This is unnecessary, if you want to pass those to double later you have to change all. So to avoid redundancy, change `height` variable data type to `int`.

Next,

change `height = textHeight.getText();` to `height = Integer.parseInt(textHeight.getText());`

Finally,

remove all type conversion inside if conditions. Like,

`Integer.parseInt(height);` to `height`.

And one last thing format the code removing unnecessary indentation and empty lines. Then it will be easy to look through the code.

Your final result should be:

```
class Disneyland {

    protected Shell shell;
    private Text textHeight;
    private int height;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Disneyland window = new Disneyland();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Disneyland.class, "/Images/1000px-Disneyland_Park_Logo.svg.png"));
        shell.setSize(600, 400);
        shell.setText("Disneyland Park Height Requirements");

        Label lblNewLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Disneyland.class, "/Images/disney_magin_disneyland_6899.png"));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(233, 10, 128, 134);

        Label lblNewLabel_1 = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel_1.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(0, 51, 255));
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("MathJax_Fraktur", 18, SWT.NORMAL));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(125, 166, 349, 27);
        lblNewLabel_1.setText("Please input your height in inches\n");

        textHeight = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        textHeight.setBounds(233, 213, 128, 27);

        Button btnSubmit = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnSubmit.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.TRANSPARENT));// COLOR_TRANSPARENT
        btnSubmit.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Disneyland.class, "/Images/disney.gif"));
        btnSubmit.setBounds(274, 261, 56, 45);
        btnSubmit.addListener(SWT.Selection, new submitButtonListener());

    }

    class submitButtonListener implements Listener {

        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            height = Integer.parseInt(textHeight.getText());

            if (height < 32) {

                MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK);
                messagebox.setText("Height limitations");
                messagebox.setMessage(
                        "For your own safety you are only allowed to use the rides with Any Height signs under adult supervision. We hope you grow up very quick :)");
                messagebox.open();
            } else {
                if (height >= 32 & height < 35) {

                    MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK);
                    messagebox.setText("Height limitations");
                    messagebox.setMessage(
                            "You are allowed to go on the Autopia accompanied by another rider 54 inches or taller");
                    messagebox.open();
                }
                if (height >= 35 & height < 40) {

                    MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK);
                    messagebox.setText("Height limitations");
                    messagebox.setMessage(
                            "You are allowed to go on the Autopia and the Gadget's Go Coaster accompanied by another rider 54 inches or taller");
                    messagebox.open();
                }
                if (height >= 40 & height < 42) {
                    MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK);
                    messagebox.setText("Height limitations");
                    messagebox.setMessage(
                            "You are allowed to go on the Autopia, Gadget's Go Coaster, the Big Thunder Mountain Railroad, Space Mountain, Splash Mountain and Star Tours accompanied by another rider 54 inches or taller");
                    messagebox.open();
                }
                if (height >= 42 & height < 46) {

                    MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK);
                    messagebox.setText("Height limitations");
                    messagebox.setMessage(
                            "You are allowed to go on the Autopia, Gadget's Go Coaster, the Big Thunder Mountain Railroad, Space Mountain, Splash Mountain, Star Tours and Matterhorn Bobsleds accompanied by another rider 54 inches or taller");
                    messagebox.open();
                }
                if (height >= 46 & height < 54) {

                    MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK);
                    messagebox.setText("Height limitations");
                    messagebox.setMessage(
                            "You are allowed to go on the Autopia, Gadget's Go Coaster, the Big Thunder Mountain Railroad, Space Mountain, Splash Mountain, Star Tours, Matterhorn Bobsleds and Indiana Jones Adventure accompanied by another rider 54 inches or taller");
                    messagebox.open();
                }

                if (height >= 54) {

                    MessageBox messagebox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK);
                    messagebox.setText("Height limitations");
                    messagebox.setMessage("You are allowed to go on the Autopia without adult supervision");
                    messagebox.open();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```